# ¿Hasta cuándo y cómo se usó el supino en español?

Tags: gramática, verbos, historia

Leyendo un resumen de la Grammatica de Nebrija, menciona entre las partes de una oración: nombre, pronombre, verbo, participio, preposición, adverbio, interjección, conjunción, gerundio y supino. Además de la falta del adjetivo, me llamó la atención el supino cuya existencia desconocía. ¿Hasta cuando existió esta forma verbal y por qué desapareció del idioma español?

Comment: En [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supino) pone que es una forma del verbo en latín pero que en español no existe. El [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/?w=supino) dice: «4. m. Gram. En algunas lenguas indoeuropeas, una de las formas nominales del verbo.»

Comment: @blonfu, mi inferencia es que si Nebrija lo menciona, en el español medieval debió existir. Que en español actual no existe, es cierto.

Comment: Igual hablaba del latín, parece que era muy fan del latín. He sacado esto de su obra: *«Tienen esso mesmo los latinos otra parte de la oración que ellos llaman supino, la cual no tiene el griego, ni el castellano, ni otra lengua de cuantas io e oído; mas cuando la bolvemos de latín en castellano, en lugar del primer supino ponemos esta preposición a con el presente del infinitivo[...]»*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resulta curioso que, una vez habiendo mencionado *verbo* como una de las partes de la oración, mencione *participio*, *gerundio* y *supino* como otras partes diferentes, dado que hoy día consideramos todo eso como conjugaciones dentro de la categoría *verbo*. Entiendo que la falta de la categoría *adjetivo* se pueda deber a que la clasificación vendría dada por cómo se forman las palabras, además de por su función (los participios, por ejemplo, generan adjetivos).

Por lo que estoy viendo, el *supino* no fue un tiempo verbal que llegara a existir en español. El *Autoridades* (tomo S-Z, 1739) dice que usado como sustantivo es una de las partes de la conjugación del verbo, que sirve para formar otros tiempos. Pero entiendo que se refiere a las conjugaciones latinas, dado que el ejemplo que pone es el siguiente:

> De cuyo *supino* sectum sale sectio, que es el corte, ò cortadúra.

Tenemos ya pues el primer ejemplo (*sección*) de palabra española proveniente de un supino. La *Gramática* actual de la RAE nos da otro ejemplo:

> ... *cohesionar*, formado sobre *cohesión*, a su vez derivado de *cohaesum*, supino de *cohaerēre* ('estar unido').

Fíjate que ya en latín se llamaba *[supino](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supino)*, de *supinus* ('perezoso', 'indiferente'), "por su vaguedad o inutilidad ya que casi todas las oraciones construidas con él frecuentemente tienen otras formas de decirse". Un tiempo verbal así de redundante no tenía sentido que se heredase, pero desde luego sí que sirvió como origen de algunas palabras. En el DLE se recogen de forma expresa, por ponjer algunos ejemplos, *[coalición](https://dle.rae.es/?w=coalici%C3%B3n&m=form)*, supino de *coalescĕre* 'reunirse, juntarse'; *[progenitura](https://dle.rae.es/?w=progenitura&m=form)*, del latín *progenĭtum*, supino de *progignĕre* 'engendrar'; *[punitivo](https://dle.rae.es/?w=punitivo&m=form)*, del latín *punītum*, supino de *punīre* 'castigar'; *[recolectar](https://dle.rae.es/?w=recolectar&m=form)*, del latín *recollectum*, supino de *recolligĕre* 'recoger'; *[remanso](https://dle.rae.es/?w=remanso&m=form)*, del latín *remansum*, supino de *remanēre* 'detenerse'; *[succión](https://dle.rae.es/?w=succi%C3%B3n&m=form)*, del latín *suctum*, supino de *sugĕre* 'chupar'; *[sutura](https://dle.rae.es/?w=sutura&m=form)*, del latín *sutūra*; de *sutum*, supino de *suĕre* 'coser'...

No he encontrado información sobre el *supino* en la primera gramática de la RAE (1771), ni su definición en el diccionario de Covarrubias (1611) ni anteriores. Por algunos textos antiguos veo que en español medieval se hacían referencias a palabras que venían "con significación de supino" (del supino latino), pero no que fueran verbos en supino propiamente dicho. Léase el siguiente ejemplo, en el que dos personajes están discutiendo sobre cuándo se escribe *a* y cuándo *ha*:

> Josep: Ya yo quedo bien aduertido de lo que dezís quando la A viniere junta; con algún nonbre propio o [a]pelativo*, de qualquiera cosa que sea, pero querría entender si puesta esta letra A con otras cosas que no sean nonbres, si se escriuirá de la mesma manera.
>   Ant[oni]o: Tanbién se ha de escriuir sin aspiraçión las vezes [que] viniere con significaçión de gerundio o supino, que son partes del verbo, porque tanbién estonçes es preposiçión, así como dezimos en latín eo ad manducandum, y* dezimos en romançe voy a comer, o voy a jugar, o a correr; pero si en medio de la A y de lo que adelante dezimos ponemos esta partícula de, en tal caso ya se haze verbo y auémosla de escreuir con h, como si dixésemos: el conde ha de comer, el rey ha de justar.
>
> Antonio de Torquemada, "Manual de escribientes", c 1552 (España).

Nótese que dice "con significación de supino" y pone el ejemplo en latín, el cual traduce al español usando el infinitivo.